# AppCode: Turn off automatic matching brace

Tags: ios, coding-style, ide, appcode

How do a I turn off AppCode generating a closing brace `}` whenever I type the opening brace `{` character?

#### What I've Tried:

I looked through: Settings --> Code Style --> Objective-C and then selected "Wrapping and Braces" and in that list, nothing jumps out as disabling the automatic right brace.

With such a sophisticated set of customizations, I know it has to be there!

#### Update:

Here's a visual on the answer provided by @pjumble

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turn off `"AppCode" -> "Preferences" -> "Editor" -> "Smart Keys" -> "Insert Pair Bracket"` and `"Insert Pair '}'"`

Comment: pjumble: I'm using AppCode 1.04, and your suggestion makes total sense - this should be it. However, even after a restart, it didn't take! At this point, I'm going to file a bug with JetBrains.

Comment: Works now - I missed the first "Insert Pair Bracket" in your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Choose Xcode > Preferences, click Text Editing, and deselect `Automatically insert closing ‘}’`.

Comment: Andrey: I'm actually using a 3rd party IDE from a company called JetBrains. It's an alternative to Xcode for some editing tasks, based on the IntelliJ IDEA platform of IDE popular in the heydays of Java development. Your tip works, but if using Apple's own Xcode.